# How to get data for past 6 weeks without using limit clause in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have below query which gives me data for previous week as shown below:

```
select distinct entity_id from abc.items
where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
```

Now I am trying to get data for past 6 weeks (not including current week) so I came up with below query but I am using `limit` clause here. Is there anyway to do the same thing without using `limit` clause?

```
select week_number, distinct entity_id from abc.items
where week_number = extract(week from current_date) - 1
and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
group by week_number
order by week_number desc
limit 6;
```

Comment: Why do you need a [Group by](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GROUP_BY_clause.html) here? You doesn't seem to do any aggregation. Is that query you are using with `limit` clause working in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
select week_number, entity_id from abc.items
where week_number >= extract(week from current_date) - 6 
      and week_number <= extract(week from current_date) - 1
      and item_type like '%Ionize - Data%'
order by week_number desc;
```

Comment: How can I get distinct `entity_id` for each week then? In my original query I had `distinct` clause on that.

Comment: You can add `distinct` in select like `select distinct week_number, entity_id from abc.items...` @AndyP

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `between` `and` operator, but in that way you need to calculate the gap of number of days in between.

Comment: can you provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: @AndyP I believe that Arun have provided what you are seeking for